# Detect touch outside Button in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a reset button that asks for confirmation first. I would like to set `isSure` to false is the user touches outside the component.

Can I do this from the Button component?

Here is my button:

```
struct ResetButton: View {
    var onConfirmPress: () -> Void;
    @State private var isSure: Bool = false;

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            if (self.isSure) {
                self.onConfirmPress();
                self.isSure.toggle();
            } else {
                self.isSure.toggle();
            }
        }) {
            Text(self.isSure ? "Are you sure?" : "Reset")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

here is one way to do it:

```
struct ContentView: View {

var onConfirmPress: () -> Void

@State private var isSure: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack {
            // a transparent rectangle under everything
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .opacity(0.001)   // <--- important
                .layoutPriority(-1)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.isSure = false
                    print("---> onTapGesture self.isSure : \(self.isSure)")
            }
            Button(action: {
                if (self.isSure) {
                    self.onConfirmPress()
                }
                self.isSure.toggle()
            }) {
                Text(self.isSure ? "Are you sure?" : "Reset").padding(10).border(Color.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Basically, we have some view, and we want a tap on its background to do something - meaning, we want to add a huge background that registers a tap. Note that `.background` is only *offered* the size of the main view, but can always set an explicit different size! If you know your size that's great, otherwise UIScreen could work...

This is hacky but seems to work!

```swift
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    private func onTapBackgroundContent(enabled: Bool, _ action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        if enabled {
            Color.clear
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 2)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture(perform: action)
        }
    }

    func onTapBackground(enabled: Bool, _ action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            onTapBackgroundContent(enabled: enabled, action)
        )
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
SomeView()
  .onTapBackground(enabled: isShowingAlert) {
    isShowingAlert = false
  }
```

This can be easily changed to take a binding:

```swift
func onTapBackground(set value: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
    background(
        onTapBackgroundContent(enabled: value.wrappedValue) { value.wrappedValue = false }
    )
}

// later...
SomeView()
    .onTapBackground(set: $isShowingAlert)
```