# SwiftUI - Detect Tap Outside View or Stack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there is a way to detect a tap outside View/HStack/VStack in SwiftUI?

I have tried to search stack overflow for a similar question, but all I could find are questions about how to dismiss the keyboard.

I have also tried to search the available HSTACK methods, and couldn't find any specific method handling click outside the view.

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is to put a ZStack surrounding the views, add a rectangle and set it's opacity to like 0.000001 or something small, but not invisible, then put an `onTapGesture` on that view, wam bam thank you done. XD

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer here will work for you: [Detect touch outside Button in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61283342/detect-touch-outside-button-in-swiftui)

```
struct ContentView: View {

var onConfirmPress: () -> Void

@State private var tappedOutsideView: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack {
            // a transparent rectangle under everything
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .opacity(0.001)   // <--- important
                .layoutPriority(-1)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.tappedOutsideView = true
                }

                // your view

                }
            }
        }
    }
```